# Android:Update otp inside view even before it got inside android message inbox

Tags: android, broadcasting, one-time-password

I use android messaging service and the scenario is to update otp automatically inside view, to reduce user effort.I use broadcasting with 1000 priority whenever my receiver got hit by android message service.it's shutting down my app after view update.Can anybody help..or give me a better approach if any.

Comment: if possible, then can you share your code or implementation? so we can identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your code?

Check if you have granted READ_SMS and RECIEVE_SMS permissions.

Comment: yes I have granted these permissions also getting otp but its too slow to catch by broadcaster.